# Redirect all pages inside a folder 301 but not folder itself

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I made a website redesign which involved creating a new structure. Now i have to redirect all pages inside a subfolder because we put the content on one page. Now i have to redirect all pages from the subfolder team. The urls from my old wordpress installation are: http://www.example.org/team/surname-lastname

Now i have to redirect all the these urls to http://www.example.org/team/

I created the following redirect:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/unternehmen/team/(.*)$ /unternehmen/team
```

But this is not working. I get an error that the redirects are creating a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.+` instead of `.*` to avoid redirect loop. Your rule can be shortened to this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(unternehmen/team)/. /$1
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this change.